# Support for radio buttons in Camunda embedded forms

Tags: camunda

How can I use radio buttons as input types in a Camunda user task form? I only found an older [thread](https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-3669) where apparently radio buttons are not supported

Does anyone have newer information?

Comment: I would also need this element because our business analyst design radio-button-heavy UIs and quite adamant

Answer (score 0):

I don't think radio buttons will ever be supported out-of-the-box in the embedded forms because their usage can vary a lot between use cases.

If you need to offer a choice (out of several possibilities) to the user, you can use the [select element](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/embedded-forms/controls/select/).
If the select element really doesn't fit your needs, you can still use the [cam-script](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/embedded-forms/javascript/cam-script/) directive to add your custom scripts.